# Binding functions with parameter in for loop - Python

Tags: python, for-loop, bind

Is there a way I can bind a function with parameter to menu items in 'for loop'?

```
for idx, val in enumerate(files):
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, lambda event: self.loadFile(val), id=100+idx)
```

The above code always passes the last 'val' of the loop to the function for all binds.

Comment: It is wx.Menu. Please see the below code.
`menu1 = wx.Menu()
for idx, val in enumerate(files):
     menu1.AppendItem(wx.MenuItem(menu1, 100+idx, ntpath.basename(val)))
     self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, lambda event: self.loadFile(val), id=100+idx)`

I am trying to add menu items dynamically based on the files in a directory.

Comment: If it's not clear from the dupe target, try default variables in the lambda: `self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, lambda event, val=val: self.loadFile(val), id=100+idx)`

Comment: @Kevin, it worked. Thanks a ton.